# Error in getting custom location or address in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to dialogflow and using version 2. Configured a project and integrated into *Facebook Messenger*.

One of my intent has a response, "*Where does this event happening?*", and there is a followup intent which expects an address or location.
So I configured the followup intent with a parameter of entity `@sys.location`. 
But this not working always.

For example, if the user gives "*Thiruvananthapuram*" (A city in Kerala, India), it is recognised as a geolocation. But if someone gives "*Trivandrum*" (a second name to the same city, recognized by Google), it's not recognised as a geolocation.

All I need in my webhook server is the latitude/longitude of the location, which is entered by user. So what are alternatives, or am I doing it wrong?

**Note-1** : Used `@sys.address`, but there is same issue.

**Note-2** : I'm thinking, there is a better way by giving `@sys.any` , collecting that info in webhook and accessing Google's *Geocode API* for lat/long. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Check the history and see what Speech to text is giving for "Thiruvananthapuram". It may be an issue of recognising the speech correctly. @sys.location which will be similar to issue with recognising Non-English names using `@sys.given-name`.